# Restarting countdown clock

Tags: java, android

This is how it looks currently:

```
final CountDownTimer countdown = new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        clock.setText("Seconds Remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
     }

     public void onFinish() {
         qcount++;

         if (qcount < 10)
         {
             this.start();
             switch (diff) {

            case 0:  //Novice difficulty
```

but it says the countdown variable isn't used and it doesn't run at all in the app.

Comment: A) variables don't start with Capital letters B) You're trying to recursively reference the thing you're creating, which is why it's telling you that indeed, it hasn't been initialized yet.

Comment: So if i understand you right you're saying i'd have to create it once initially outside of here? How does the declaration for a countdown look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use Countdown in the anonymous class that'll instantiate it. Countdown is an instance of that class, onFinish() is called on that instance.

You should call start() on the instance onFinish() was called on, so use 'this'.

```
this.start();
```

**EDIT** : Look at it as if you were simply creating a new class, which is basically what you're doing. In the new class definition, "Countdown" is not a variable, so you can't use it. You'd simply call start on the object onFinish() was called on. However since you're using an anonymous class, you can still access your outer class's variables from within your anonymous class, which in this case leads to confusion and error.

Comment: I'm not sure i follow, could you elaborate?

Comment: I've tried changing it so it says this.start(); inside the onFinish method now it tells me that my countdown variable is unused and the timer doesn't run at all when i launch the app

Comment: Well unless you're using eventhandlers the onTick(long mil) and onFinish() methods won't get called. There's not enough information in your example code to determine exactly what's wrong though.

Comment: Thank you, I've figured it out.